# Как автоматически найти COM-порт подключенной Arduino?

Tags: java, arduino, serial

Ситуация стандартная. Arduino UNO подключается к компьютеру через COM-порт. Я пишу скетч для Arduino и я же пишу приложение для компьютера, которое будет с нею общаться. А значит, для начала приложение должно подключиться к COM-порту.

Но не все так просто. Потому что номера COM-порта у приложения не будет. И пользователь его не выберет. Оно само должно найти именно Arduino, и именно эту Arduino, среди (возможно) множества других COM-портов. И методом тыка не хотелось бы - побочек много.

Очевидно, что именно в случае с Arduino это более-менее реализуемо, т.к. там не просто serial, а USB-Serial, то есть при подключении где-то в системе появляется не только COM-порт, но и какая-то инфа насчет USB-устройства, и в том числе соответствие между USB и COM-портом.

Есть даже конкретная идея - использовать ветку HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB. Именно там хранятся соответствия между номером COM-порта - и PID, VID, FriendlyName и другими полезными свойствами подключенного USB-устройства для идентификации Arduino вообще (если конечно она оригинальная, ну или нужен огромный словарь данных) или даже конкретного экземпляра.

Но:

1. Я не хочу изобретать велосипед. Если есть готовая библиотека - я ее
   хочу.
2. Желательно кроссплатформенно.
3. Хотелось бы "правильное" со всех сторон решение. Ветки реестра нечасто являются единственным способом получить данные - бывает, что есть более стандартный способ, а стандартные способы иногда могут "пережить" больше версий ОС, чем "самодельные".

Язык приложения - Java.

Comment: В https://github.com/wjwwood/serial есть возможность получить список всех последовательных портов в системе через serial::list_ports() (в списке будут также и VID/PID каждого найденного USB/COM порта), дальше можно отфильтровать список по VID/PID вашего устройства.